# Why use OAuth 2 vs OpenID Connect in Azure B2C for mobile apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

[Azure B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code) reads:

- We recommend **OpenID Connect** if you're building a **web application** that is hosted on a server and accessed through a browser.
- If you want to add identity management to your **mobile or desktop applications** by using Azure AD B2C, you should **use OAuth 2.0 rather than OpenID Connect**.

My question is why?  The documentation doesn't express why one protocol is better for web apps an the other is better for desktop & mobile clients.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it is a bit baffling.

I don't believe this is about choosing OpenID Connect for web apps or OAuth for native apps.

I believe it is recommending you use a confidential client flow for web apps, as described by [Azure Active Directory B2C: Web sign-in with OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc), and a public client flow for native apps, as described by [Azure Active Directory B2C: OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code).

Comment: Maybe, its still odd because:

1.  OIDC still offers the implicit flow that doesn't require a client secret so that's suitable for a public client. This should give all the benefit of an auth code plus an added id_token.

2. The recommendation for authorization flow MIGHT be to satisfy the need for refresh_tokens but:

a) that's inconsistent with it being a public client since a refresh_token requires a client secret which shouldn't be on a public client  

b) OIDC offers this same ability with scope="id_token offline_access" & response_type = "id_token code"

What am i missing?

Comment: Hi @frigon I don't believe you are missing anything. :) Clients, confidential or public, can use the OpenID Connect or OAuth protocols. The main difference is whether an ID token is issued or not. BTW, a public client can be issued with a refresh token, using the authorization code or hybrid flow without requiring a client secret.